# Get-PSDrive select formatting

Tags: powershell, select, format

I'm trying to do simple select formatting in  powershell with gdr ( Get-PSDrive ), namely:

When you exec gdr with no parameters, you receive statistics in GB

```
PS > gdr

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) 
C                 187.31        278.10
```

How do I select the colums in GB -"Used (GB)", , without it converting it to bytes ?

```
gdr -PSProvider filesystem | select Name, Used

Name     Used
----     ----
C       201127354368
```

I don't want to further convert it  @{Used="} style, I need to just "select column the way it is  " :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calculated property.

```
get-psdrive -psprovider FileSystem |
  select-object Name,@{Name="Used"; Expression={$_.Used/1GB}}
```

See help for `Select-Object`.

Comment: Yes, but for 3 colums I need to write a page of select :)

Is there anything the " awk " -way : awk '{print $1 }' ( column one) etc  -> print the column the way it is at the moment ? :)

Comment: If you don't want to change the property, just specify the property's name with `Select-Object`. Calculated properties are for when you want to do something with the property before you output it (hence the name).